# Android Jetpack Compose - Auth navigation flow with deeplink support

Tags: android, authentication, deep-linking, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm developing an app where I have 3 screens: Login screen, Quotes list screen and Quote detail screen.
I’d like to implement a simple conditional navigation between Login and Quotes list screens based on the user `isLoggedIn` boolean state with deeplink support.

I read a [good article](https://www.ittybittyapps.com/blog/2022-10-19-navigation-compose/) and tried to follow the [official navigation principles](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nested-nav)(single NavHost, fixed start destination) and [deeplink support](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#deeplinks).
Unfortunately, the official documentation doesn't cover it fully.

Here is a base code of navigation logic from the project:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val isLoggedIn by viewModel.isLoggedIn.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            // without it the deeplink works
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = isLoggedIn) {
                if (isLoggedIn) {
                    navController.navigate(QuotesNavigationGraph) {
                        popUpTo(0)
                    }
                } else {
                    navController.navigate(LoginNavigationGraph) {
                        popUpTo(0)
                    }
                }
            }

            TemplateTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    NavHost(
                        navController = navController,
                        startDestination = QuotesNavigationGraph
                    ) {
                        navigation(
                            route = LoginNavigationGraph,
                            startDestination = LoginNavigationRoute,
                        ) {
                            loginScreen()
                        }

                        navigation(
                            route = QuotesNavigationGraph,
                            startDestination = QuotesNavigationRoute
                        ) {
                            quotesScreen(
                                onQuoteClick = { quoteId ->
                                    navController.navigateToQuoteDetail(quoteId)
                                }
                            )
                            quoteDetailScreen(
                                onBackClick = {
                                    navController.navigateUp()
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    userDataRepository: UserDataRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val isLoggedIn = userDataRepository.isLoggedIn
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
            initialValue = true
        )
}
```

```
const val LoginNavigationGraph = "login_graph"
const val LoginNavigationRoute = "login_route"

fun NavGraphBuilder.loginScreen() {
    composable(route = LoginNavigationRoute) {
        LoginRoute()
    }
}
```

```
const val QuotesNavigationGraph = "quotes_graph"
const val QuotesNavigationRoute = "quotes_route"

fun NavGraphBuilder.quotesScreen(
    onQuoteClick: (Int) -> Unit,
) {
    composable(route = QuotesNavigationRoute) {
        QuotesRoute(
            onQuoteClick = onQuoteClick
        )
    }
}
```

```
const val QuoteDetailNavigationRoute = "quote_detail_route"
const val QuoteIdArg = "quoteId"

fun NavController.navigateToQuoteDetail(
    quoteId: Int = -1,
    navOptions: NavOptions? = null
) {
    this.navigate(
        QuoteDetailNavigationRoute.plus("/$quoteId"),
        navOptions
    )
}

fun NavGraphBuilder.quoteDetailScreen(
    onBackClick: () -> Unit
) {
    composable(
        route = QuoteDetailNavigationRoute.plus("/{$QuoteIdArg}"),
        arguments = listOf(
            navArgument(QuoteIdArg) { type = NavType.IntType },
        ),
        deepLinks = listOf(
            navDeepLink {
                uriPattern = "https://template.com/{$QuoteIdArg}"
            }
        ),
    ) {
        QuoteDetailRoute(
            onBackClick = onBackClick
        )
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ....
        <activity
            android:name=".feature.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Template">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data
                    android:host="template.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In general almost everything works with this approach:

- if user `isLoggedIn == true` the app opens main screen - Quotes list
- if user `isLoggedIn == false` the app opens the Login screen, but shows  Quotes list for a second(that isn’t good)

Problems with this approach:

- deeplink doesn’t work with this approach, if user `isLoggedIn == true` it opens Quotes list instead of Quote detail screen
- if I remove the LaunchedEffect block from the MainActivity then deeplink opens Quote detail screen as expected but it breaks login navigation flow

So my questions are:

1. Do I implement the app navigation in correct way?
2. If I don’t, can you recommend some good solution/example/project/library that can cover login flow with deeplink support and that is following the official navigation principles?

What I’d like to achieve:

- if user `isLoggedIn == true` the app opens main screen - Quotes list
- if user `isLoggedIn == false` the app opens the Login screen
- if user `isLoggedIn == true` deeplink should open Quote detail screen
- if user `isLoggedIn == false` app should open the Login screen, and after the user is logged in, it should navigate the user to Quote detail screen

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @PVD I haven't yet

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in my project would be like that with your code:

```
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = if (isLoggedIn) QuotesNavigationGraph else LoginNavigationGraph
) { ... }
```

I know that this are not a good practice because makes startDestination mutable, but is a good solution until you have one better.